# Ensuring dynamically added Dojo Dijits are registered in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to dynamically create Dijits to add N rules to a particular form.  Currently I am adding them with the following javascript.

```
var value = new dijit.form.Select({
    id: "value_" + counter,
    store: ValueStore,
    searchAttr: "description"       
},
"stateSelect" + counter);
value.placeAt(form, "last");
value.startup();
```

This is creating the element correctly in the form, but it is not associated when the form actually posts.  I know Dojo is recognizing the Dijit because the styling is correct.  How can I make sure they are included in the DOM form?

Comment: You mean, programmatically? Or manually? Manually, it's easiest with Firebug IMO. Right-click the form, "Inspect element", and navigate through the DOM tree shown to the left.

Comment: Programatically.  The visual elements of the form are correct and the new elements are added within the </form> tag...but when I submit the form, the new elements are not included.

Comment: what is "stateSelect" + counter?  Is that the id of an existing node? If so, you shouldn't need to place it.  Shouldn't you have a name attribute for it to be submitted as part of a form?

Comment: peller: You are totally right.  That was the error in the code.  I removed that stateSelect and added a name parameter and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try giving your `select` a `name` attribute in addition to its `id`?  HTML forms `POST` their elements by `name`, not by `id`.